# How does DLL injection work with games if memory addresses change every time you start the game?

Tags: memory, dynamic, memory-address

Ok, I'm pretty much an amateur when it comes to memory hacking/memory management (whatever you want to call it) but I followed a simple tutorial on writing a DLL. I used Cheat Engine to find a certain address of a certain value, then closed the game and restarted it. I tried to find the same value but it had a different address (dynamic memory I'm assuming).

So, ok, I was supposed to copy this address and put it into a part of the code of the DLL before injecting it (it was supposedly a while(true) loop to constantly reset the value in that address to 0), but wouldn't it be useless to use DLL injection if the address is going to change every time I start the game, or am I missing something here? How do I keep finding a value that has a dynamic address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping address in C++ hacking game code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775481/keeping-address-in-c-hacking-game-code)

Comment: In case of Cheat Engine, just take a look at the tutorial. If you hadn't skipped it, this question wouldn't come up. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm also an amateur, And in some ways may know even less than you.

However I believe from my experiences there are ways to find "pointers" within memory editors, The pointer is (I believe) a morsel of code that randomly generates the address that you actually want, Find the Static pointer address, and you should be able to route your .dll to the dynamic Value address.

Hope it was of some help, I would look into pointers, how they work, and how to use them.

Comment: A pointer is not any measure of 'code'; `morsel` or otherwise.